# How to fix the issue? " psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required "

Tags: database, postgresql

[while installing postgresql in pem server installation details i am facing a issue regarding host
how to solve this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6clh.png)

I retried many times.i tried to change the host name as SSL but it is not coming i am not understanding how to solve this issue if anyone knows please help with it

Comment: Clearly the server needs to be configured to support SSL, or the client needs to be configured not to demand it.  Which of those is your preference?